# css float not cancelling

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 5 paragraph markers that are all floating next to each other using a CSS Class.

When I add my 6th paragraph marker I assumed and wanted it to move down, however it is floating next to the other 5.

I created this jsfiddle so you can see what I have so far,
    `<http://jsfiddle.net/rtze3a8g/1/>`

Basically I am trying do design my own tab bar.

New to this so I hope I explained it properly.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Please place your code directly within the question. If you need help formatting the code, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help or click ? in the rich text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtze3a8g/2/)

When you have float elements adjacent each others, if you want some of them take the entire line (acting as 'block' element), you need to use `clear: both`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use clear:left to clear float left

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

html {
 font-size: 100%;
 }

body {
 font: 62.5%/1.5 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #000000;
 background: #6D9BF1;
 padding: 20px;
 }

#wrapper {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 700px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }

p {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    
 }
p.newLine{clear:left;}
p.ribbon{
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 }

p.ribbon:hover{
 background-color: #87CEEB;
 color: white;
}

p.reset{
 float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <title>Enter Title Here</title>
 <script>
  function newfunction(){
  }
 </script>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <p class="ribbon">Home</p>
  <p class="ribbon">History</p>
  <p class="ribbon">Location</p>
  <p class="ribbon">Photos</p>
  <p class="ribbon">Contact Us</p>
  <p class="newLine">This is test information</p>
  <p>This is test information</p>
 </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```